# What is the difference between normal and directional derivatives?

Tags: mathematical-physics

On pages 22 and 23 of H. K. Dass's *Mathematical Physics*, I read that both normal and directional derivatives are solved by finding the gradient of a surface and then putting a Cartesian value of a point on that surface in the the answer of gradient. I don't understand what makes them different or why they have different names if they are the same thing. For example, eigenvalues of a matrix have other names but it is specified that they are the different names of the same value.

Comment: Thank You. I am humbly grateful

Comment: I misinterpreted your question. I deleted my previous comment since it is not correct.

Comment: it's okay. to err is human , ain't no computer.